# How can I avoid random graphical freezes on Ubuntu 20.10 with X11 + propriety Nvidia drvieers

Tags: nvidia, xorg, nvidia-geforce, nvidia-prime, 20.10

I'm using Ubuntu 20.10 with the Unity Desktop + X11 (I'm aware that Unity is no longer supported, and that the GNOME desktop is the new desktop, but I can't get on with it), and I've just done a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.10 Groovy Gorilla onto a brand-new laptop. This went fine, except that about once a day, the entire screen freezes and locks up. Sometimes I can still control the mouse, but this too will disappear after a few seconds.

My system details:

- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10875H CPU @ 2.30GHz
- 32 GiB 2666MHz RAM
- Disk: SSD, NVME, LUKS encrypted + LVM
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce RTX 2060 (using the propriety drivers - version 450; using the `NVIDIA On-Demand` PRIME profile)
- `uname -a`: `Linux LAPTOP_NAME 5.8.0-26-generic #27-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 21 22:29:16 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I have checked the system logs (`/var/log/syslog`), and no unusual log messages appear just before or after the freeze. It also does not unfreeze, so I have to forcefully power off the system by holding the power button.

It does not appear to have a specific cause either. It has happened when I was reading a news article in Firefox, and it has also happened in the middle of a YouTube video. It also happened in the middle of a video call too.

I have another Laptop with a Radeon R7 M445 on Ubuntu 20.04, which does not have this problem.

Does anyone know how I can prevent these random graphical freezes?

Comment: I have the exact same issue with Ubuntu 20.10, but in my case it only happens once when I want to open an application (doesn't matter which app) for the first time after a reboot. However, gnome-shell restarts itself and everything becomes normal afterward...